# Preventing reverse-engineering of a Java game source code using client server model

Tags: java, client-server, reverse-engineering

I'm looking to find ways to prevent a Java made game such as runescape from being hacked by using the client server model for keeping the important source code in the server and sending the data to the client. My question is how would it be possible to make something like this, any information links or articles would be helpful.

I'm also wondering what kind of information can someone send from a server that can also be rendered in a 3d graphics engine, or how is it done?

Comment: Short answer: you can't prevent reverse engineering.

Comment: Yeah I know the question is broad, thats why I asked for links to articles if possible. I tried google for this but all I could find are mentions of the client server model.

Comment: @lost this isn't a forum, sorry

Comment: @Woot4Moo Lucas gave me a useful article, I wished you would do the same, thanks.

Comment: @lost as I stated below,  I think this is a bit out of your depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm also wondering what kind of
>   information can someone send from a
>   server that can also be rendered in a
>   3d graphics engine, or how is it done?

While I am not a game/3d developer myself, I found this article illuminating (browse their wiki for more!)

[Source Multiplayer Networking](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking) [valvesoftware.com]

Answer (score 4):

You can't do much about the client being decompiled - you can obfuscate your source code to make it more difficult to reverse-engineer. This will make getting readable source code slightly more difficult, but not impossible. A determined and skilled user could stil reverse-engineer the client.

However you can do a lot of work on the server where the source code can't be recovered. For example you could code the [artifical intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) for [NPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-player_character)s, and all physics calculations on the server and just send the results to the clients.

In fact these sorts of calculations should be done on the server anyway to keep the game consistent and to prevent clients from cheating.

The client will typically do most of the presentation such as 3D rendering. This is usually done locally for performance reasons, so that the rendering can take full advantage of the graphics card in the client.

Comment: @lost_with_coding   NPC = non-player-character  (a computer character)

Comment: @lost doesn't runescape have NPC's?  Is this a homework question?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Homework question, no.. I'm just trying to develop a game.

Comment: @lost and you don't understand basic terminology?  I think this may be out of your depth.

Comment: @ Woot4Moo I'm one guy trying to make a game like runescape.

Comment: @Bolo: Thanks - I updated to my answer to include that link. :)

Answer (score 2):

Every program, given sufficient manpower and time, can be reverse engineered. If you can give a team of testers/developers the program to use for a while, they are going to be able to mimic its functionality. A great example is the MMORPG games out there (think about Ultima Online and the plethora of open source Shards that mimic it and work with the UO client).

You can obfuscate the code, and make it hard to decompile etc.,  but at the beginning of a project that is beyond overkill. Make something people will be willing to pay for, take the very basic source-code protection precautions and then rely on copyright law to shield you from reserve engineering (its not perfect, but nothing is).

Answer (score 0):

The client server model in theory could prevent many forms of cheating by only sending specific information between the two, notably input from the player and the players view of the game from the server.

However in practice this is rarely done.  Lag prevents a real time game from playing adequately without having the client handle at least part of the positioning and physics work.  This means a player has copies of information stored locally that they shouldn't have in the game.

The client server model also does little for hacks with macro actions.  Players can hack their clients to repeat actions or assist actions (such as aiming).  Certain other information can recreated on a hacked client from the information the server provides.

Rendering the 3d scene itself falls into three camps.

1. Each client can render it however
   they feel.  It doesn't matter if you
   use sword swing A or sword swing B
   if they don't interact differently
   with the environment.
2. Clients can make a best guess, and have to reconcile if wrong.  I lose connection for 2 seconds.  My character keeps running on your screen because your client assumes that's what I would be doing.  I reconnect, but I had told the client to turn.  Either I jump on your screen or mine.
3. The server decides.  The server says a barrel falls along algorithmic path C.  This is most common when the falling barrel interacts with the environment i.e. it can hit and damage other things.